# Ormlite Inner Join em cinco tabelas

Tags: android, sql, ormlite

Eu quero criar alguns JOIN em cinco tabelas como este exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA AS TA
    INNER JOIN TableB AS TB ON TA.Id = TB.IdTA
    INNER JOIN TableC AS TC ON TB.IdTC = TC.Id
    INNER JOIN TableD AS TD ON TC.Id = TD.IdTC
    INNER JOIN TableE AS TE ON TD.IdTE = TE.Id
WHERE TE.Id = 30085
```

Obs: As TableB e TableD são tabelas `N-M`

Estou um pouco confuso de como fazer isso no Ormlite do Android, alguém poderia me ajudar com essa query ou me fornecer um passo a passo?

Comment: `Primeiro:`, não colocar `*`, ou seja, discriminar os campos, `Segundo:` se as TableB e TableD existe uma junção entre elas e se for necessário coloque a tabela intermediária com duas comparações `on` **comparação** e `and` **comparação** . Obs: seria uma das formas talvez depende muito do que você deseja comparar !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue resposta adaptada [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301418/ormlite-inner-join-on-three-tables):

Vai ser algo mais ou menos assim *(adaptando pro seu exemplo)*:

```
// Começa a primeira query
QueryBuilder<TableA, Integer> TableAQb = TableADao.queryBuilder();
QueryBuilder<TableB, Integer> TableBQb = TableBDao.queryBuilder();
// Join entre TableA e TableB 
TableAQb.join(TableBQb);
//TERCEIRA QUERY
QueryBuilder<TableC, Integer> TableCQb =
    TableCDao.queryBuilder();
TableCQb.where().gt("mixedvalue", 100);
// join TableC
TableCQb.join(TableAQb);
List<TableC> TableCQb.query();
```

Seguindo assim para as demais tabelas.

Lembrando que há suporte para "queries cruas", inclusive o método [`Dao.queryRaw()`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#queryRaw%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29) onde você pode utilizar sua própria query. Segue [documentação](http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-queries).

Comment: Ae! Consegui fazer para as 5 tabelas... Obrigado!